# Delete data uploaded on a certain date but there is no date column in the table

Tags: sql, oracle, sysdate

I am trying to delete data from an Oracle table. I have uploaded the data today but there is no date column so I cannot filter by that and delete. I have to find how to get the data that were uploaded today in the table and then filter by that and delete.

I would like something like this:

```
delete from mytable
where  uploaded_date = trunc(sysdate)
```

I am using Toad.

Thanks

Comment: Without a date column, you have to resort to the logs generated by the update or other metadata about the load.

Comment: Possibly you can [`select * from mytable as of timestamp ...`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_flashback.htm#ADFNS01003) syntax (Flashback Query), depending on your Oracle version and licensing.

Comment: Why not just add a date column !

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to go back in time to `yesterday` for your table's data. If so, you may use `Flashback Table` operation of Oracle DB, provided

- Your database's version is at least `10g`.
- You must have been granted the `FLASHBACK ANY TABLE` system privilege or you must have the `FLASHBACK` object privilege on the table.
- You must have `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `DELETE`, and `ALTER` privileges on the table.
- Undo information retained in the undo tablespace must go far enough back in time to satisfy the specified target point in time or `SCN` for the `FLASHBACK TABLE` operation. (For this option, you may consult your DBA).
- Row movement must be **already** enabled on the table for which you are issuing the `FLASHBACK TABLE` statement. You can enable row movement with this statement :

  `SQL> ALTER TABLE mytable ENABLE ROW MOVEMENT;`

> but if not already ENABLED, don't use this sentence to ALTER the
>   table, since your undo data is lost by issuing a DDL. In such a case
>   you may recover by using ***Flashback Query***
>   `select * from mytable as of timestamp timestamp '2018-01-14';`

and you can go back to yesterday's data by issuing(*today's date is 2018-01-14*) :

```
  SQL> FLASHBACK TABLE mytable TO TIMESTAMP 
      TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-01-14 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') 
      ENABLE TRIGGERS;
```

You may omit `ENABLE TRIGGERS` part at the end, if your table doesn't have any trigger( The default for a `FLASHBACK TABLE` operation is for triggers on a table to be disabled ).

> **Important Note** : Before applying Flashback Table operation you should
>   take a backup as `CREATE TABLE mytable_ AS SELECT * FROM mytable;`

Comment: Flashback is a good idea but **don't run that alter table statement yet** or your old data will be lost.  Instead, use a flashback query such as `select * from mytable as of timestamp timestamp '2018-01-14';` to help identify new rows.  But do it quickly before your UNDO data ages out!  Depending on your system configuration you may only have UNDO available for a few minutes.

Comment: @JonHeller thank you so much, you're exactly right, i didn't notice.